Extract Only Secret Values with EKS + Vault CSI Provider
I am using the Vault CSI Provider with EKS to load secrets stored in Vault KV into my deployment as a JSON file. Here are the relevant configurations:
SecretProviderClass configuration:
apiVersion: secrets-store.csi.x-k8s.io/v1
kind: SecretProviderClass
metadata:
  name: CENSORED-secret-provider-class
  namespace: CENSORED
spec:
  parameters:
    objects: |
      - objectName: "CENSORED"
        secretPath: "CENSORED"
        secretKey: ""
        template: |
          {
            "BotToken": "{{ .data.BotToken }}",
            "Mongo": {
              "db": "{{ .data.Mongo.db }}",
              "host": "{{ .data.Mongo.host }}",
              "password": "{{ .data.Mongo.password }}",
              "port": {{ .data.Mongo.port }},
              "username": "{{ .data.Mongo.username }}"
            }
          }
    roleName: CENSORED
    vaultAddress: CENSORED
  provider: vault

Secret stored in Vault KV:
/ $ vault kv get CENSORED
====== Data ======
Key         Value
---         -----
BotToken    CENSORED
Mongo       map[db:CENSORED host:CENSORED password:CENSORED port:CENSORED username:CENSORED]

Deployment.yaml:
          volumeMounts:
            - name: secret
              mountPath: CENSORED
              readOnly: true
      volumes:
      - name: secret
        csi:
          driver: secrets-store.csi.k8s.io
          readOnly: true
          volumeAttributes:
            secretProviderClass: "CENSORED"
            secretKey: ""


My Situation:
I am trying to use Vault CSI Provider to load secrets stored in Vault KV into my deployment.yaml. The service expects the secret in the form of an ENV.json file.
While I have successfully loaded the secrets from Vault KV, I am encountering an issue where additional fields (like request_id, lease_id, etc.) are added to the JSON, making it difficult for me to access the desired data.
This is how the secret looks after being loaded:
AS-IS:
/CENSORED # cat CENSORED.json 
{
  "request_id": "...",
  "lease_id": "",
  "lease_duration": 2764800,
  "renewable": false,
  "data": {
    "BotToken": "...",
    "Mongo": {
      "db": "...",
      "host": "...",
      "password": "...",
      "port": ...,
      "username": "..."
    }
  }
}

I want to extract only the values under the data field and remove the extra fields like request_id, lease_id, etc., so that the output looks like this:
TO-BE:
/CENSORED # cat CENSORED.json 
{
  "BotToken": "...",
  "Mongo": {
    "db": "...",
    "host": "...",
    "password": "...",
    "port": ...,
    "username": "..."
  }
}

Question:
How can I modify my setup so that only the contents under the data field are included in the JSON file, without the additional metadata like request_id and lease_id?

when you set the secretKey: "", it will have the metadata. The only solution is to copy all the needed data (AS json object) to a new key (let's say Appinfo in the same path) and retrieve that key:
vault kv put YOUR_PATH_IN_VAULT -<<EOF
{
  "Appinfo": {
    "BotToken": "...",
    "Mongo": {
      "db": "...",
      "host": "...",
      "password": "...",
      "port": "...",
      "username": "..."
    }
  }
}
EOF

and then in your SecretProviderClass configuration:
apiVersion: secrets-store.csi.x-k8s.io/v1
kind: SecretProviderClass
metadata:
  name: CENSORED-secret-provider-class
  namespace: CENSORED
spec:
  parameters:
    objects: |
      - objectName: "CENSORED"
        secretPath: "CENSORED"
        secretKey: "Appinfo"
    roleName: CENSORED
    vaultAddress: CENSORED
  provider: vault

